# How can I block ads on Windows 8.1 Book Reader?

Tags: windows-8.1, firewall, advertisements

When I read epub books using Windows 8.1 Book Reader, I see ads at the bottom of the screen. I have tried to change settings in the default firewall included with Windows to no avail.  I downloaded and installed http://www.privacyware.com/personal_firewall.html but the Book Reader program is not listed as a running application.

Edit: I suspect that this is because this program runs as a metro apps under WWAHost.exe, one of potentially many such programs.  Since WWAHost.exe is a generic program, it might be counterproductive to prevent it from accessing the internet.  This is just guesswork of my part.

Comment: Is it a metro app, or a regular program? Can you perhaps provide a link to the program's website to help identify it, because currently I have no idea which program you are refering to. You can use your taskmanager to help indentify the file(s) that need to be blocked in your firewall; use the `details` tab.

Comment: I see in your other comment you've said this program came with your Windows 8.1. Perhaps it was installed by your manufacterer, because I do not see this app on mine. All I see is `Reader` which does not support epub books.

Comment: It is an app (not a regular program) which has no "about" information.  Based on the filename (which contains the string AlexDrel), I suspect it is a version of http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-ca/app/bookreader/06cf41da-91d5-45d4-b9a0-fa8204c44c0b - author's website is http://bookreader.netau.net/ which does not include any mention of adware support.  It was included with my Lenovo's Windows installation.

Comment: I do not have a Microsoft Account; I use a local account so I cannot install metro apps. However when you run it, it should appear in your taskmanager's `details` tab. The name may be different, but it will likely say something like BookReader in the description. If it shows up in the `processes` tab you can right click on it, and choose `go to details` to find it in the `details` tab. You can then right click on the file, and choose `open file location` to get the full path. The program may have multiple files, it will take trial and error to figure out which one(s) to block in your firewall.

Comment: R.H.: It's supposedly in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps.  However, I only see C:\Program Files (X86)\ ... and the system just refuses to let me see the exact file.

Comment: What were the names (or name) under the details tab? You could try searching the name in Explorer to find the location.

Comment: WWAHost.exe was the name that was hihglighted when clicking on the details tab.   Looking at properties, I get 2136AlexDrel.BookReader_1.3.0.0_neutral__7y746zsha525p  (supposedly in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps).  Doing a search for bookreader in explorer, I see a few instances, one of which is under C:\Utilisateurs\Andre\Apdata\Local\Microsoft\"shortcut" where the "shortcut" (which stands for the French equivalent name) properties are such that the "target" is actually left blank.  There are three directory listed containing "bookreader", one dll and one dll.aux file.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default app in Windows 8.1 called "Book Reader". There are third-party apps made by independent developed with this title. These probably use the ads to support the developers (that's how they can give the app away for "free" even though it took hard work to develop it.

If you wish to use an ad-free ebook reader app, look for one that specifies it is ad-free.

Comment: You make a very good point about looking for an alternative program.  However, I am still puzzled as to how I can not block communication from this program (which was included by default with my Windows 8.1 install).  Even if disabling communications would disable the program itself, I'd still be fine with this, as I do understand the need to support developers; however, the fact that I seemingly can't block it is ... disturbing.

Comment: We don't do software recommendations so if your looking for an alternative choice this isn't the place to find it.

Comment: I am not looking for software recommendation - but how to use a firewall to block such an app.

Comment: Just to clarify: I thought I knew how to use a firewall - but window's firewall ignores the settings for this app and personal_firewall does not even list it as a running program.

Comment: @Andre I haven't used it recently, but Comodo used to make an excellent Firewall, that supported prompt-based per application blocking as well as manual rules. It's free to!